# Is it possible to retrieve the facebook app authorization code from the canvas tutorial using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-apps

This is the code from the canvas tutorial
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

This gets the authorization code, redirects the user back to the canvas page and displays the code in the url.

Something like, http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp/?code=1234thecode5678

So, is it possible to do it using ajax and get the code without redirecting? Instead of this method?

Thanks in advance

```
     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook JS SDK to log the user in with out having to refresh or redirect the user.
Taken from the [Facebook JS SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) under the topic [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log('Logged out.');
       });
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

**Note** : This is the implementation if you are using oAuth 2.0 (and you really should be).  Taken from the same url :

> Without OAuth 2.0, scope should instead be replaced with perms, and
>   response.authResponse replaced with response.session. **Remember that
>   all apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 by October 1, 2011.**